# Installing Subversion on Lacie network space max 2

Tags: svn, installation, nas

Has anyone done it, Installed Subversion on Lacie network space max 2? If so, could you pleeeaase post how you did it? I'd hate to have a server running just to use SVN at home. The ideal solution would be installing SVN to my Lacie that is up and running 24/7 already. Just have no idea how to do it. ALL HELP APPRECIATED!1!

Comment: You wanted http://serverfault.com/, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Lacie Network Space Max 2 is just a file server - is that right?  If so, then you'll *probably* be able to get away with setting up a local repository on the shared drive it presents. Instructions for doing that with TortoiseSVN are [here.](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository.html#tsvn-repository-create-tortoisesvn)

Answer (score 1):

I have done this on my Lacie Network 2Big, I hope it is similar for your Lacie Network space max2.

Here's a tutorial to do it on your Network Space Max: http://lacie.nas-central.org/wiki/Category:Network_Space

Inside the tutorial, you will find the link to the subversion server.

Here's a tutorial to get access to root telnet and ssh for Network 2Big:
http://lacie.nas-central.org/wiki/Category:2big_Network

good luck.